# how to get exif from photo?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing, exif

i want to get exif from picture. how i do this optimally?

```
NSData *dataOfImageFromGallery = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (workingImage,0.5);

CGImageSourceRef imageSource;
imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)dataOfImageFromGallery, NULL);

if (imageSource == NULL) { 
    // Error loading image ... 
     return; } 

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], (NSString *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache, nil]; 
CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options); 

if (imageProperties) { 
    NSNumber *width = (__bridge NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth); 
    NSNumber *height = (__bridge NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight); 

    CFRelease(imageProperties); 

    NSLog(@"width: %@", width);
    NSLog(@"height: %@", height);  
}
```

this print `width` and `height` but EXIF properties is about 40 in `CGImageProperties.h` in `ImageIO.h` library file, and i don't know how to print all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Use exiftool,
my [simple project](http://www.developers-life.com/geo-photo-info-editor.html) based on exiftool

Comment: i don't understand. i must write this function. you give me your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting IOS 4 and above you should use ALAssetsLibrary.
There are a lot of threads here that describe the ALAssetsLibrary and how to get EXIF data from the image.

Be aware though, if user doesn't allow location services for your APP ALAssetsLibrary will not work and will report an error (access denied)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is log the entire contents of the `imageProperties` dictionary, then just do:

`NSLog(@"imageProperties: %@", imageProperties);`

If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify your question.